# Why is RepositoryItemReaderBuilder stricter than creating a bean RepositoryItemReader

Tags: spring, spring-batch

`RepositoryItemReaderBuilder` was introduced in Spring Batch 4.0 (see [notes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.0.x/reference/html/whatsnew.html#whatsNewBuilders)).

Why creating an instance of `RepositoryItemReader` with `RepositoryItemReaderBuilder` is stricter than (or not consistent with) creating a `RepositoryItemReader` Bean with Spring ?

### Conditions required for *initializing bean RepositoryItemReader*

3 fields checked :

```java
    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        Assert.state(repository != null, "A PagingAndSortingRepository is required");
        Assert.state(pageSize > 0, "Page size must be greater than 0");
        Assert.state(sort != null, "A sort is required");
    }
```

### Conditions required for *RepositoryItemReaderBuilder.build()*

more fields checked, like `this.methodName` or `this.name` :

```java
    public RepositoryItemReader<T> build() {
        if (this.repositoryMethodReference != null) {
            ...
        }

        Assert.notNull(this.sorts, "sorts map is required.");
        Assert.notNull(this.repository, "repository is required.");
        Assert.hasText(this.methodName, "methodName is required.");
        if (this.saveState) {
            Assert.state(StringUtils.hasText(this.name), "A name is required when saveState is set to true.");
        }

        RepositoryItemReader<T> reader = new RepositoryItemReader<>();
        reader.set...
        reader.set...
        return reader;
    }
```

---

### Sources :

- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/4.3.x/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/data/RepositoryItemReader.java
- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/4.3.x/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/data/builder/RepositoryItemReaderBuilder.java

Answer (score 0):

That should not be the case. For consistency, I agree that the same validation rules should apply either by using the builder or when directly creating the reader/writer without a builder.

Please open an issue on Github and we will see how to make these validation rules consistent. Thank you upfront.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to unit test that more thorougly to see if this is really a problem at runtime.

Comment: OK issue submitted : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/4276